# Recommend a reasonably priced email provider?

Tags: email, hosting, smtp, pop3

We have around 50 domains that aren't core/key business but ideally we want to be able to have the MX records pointing to someone to accept mail for the following:

abuse@ and postmaster@ for all the domains.

various forwarding aliases i.e. sales@ goes to someone@ourcompany dot com

on three or four of the domains we want to have a handful of pop3 mailboxes

smtp relay would be good for the pop3 users

Any suggestions would be appreciated, our registrar doesn't offer this (well they do, but at prices more suited to primary business domains).

I know I could do it in-house with hmail or mailenable but if there is a cheap and reliable way that just takes the hassle away...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Apps has a free version http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html. Just make one of the domains your main one that you use to set up the Google Apps account, then add all the other domains as domain aliases.

Then create accounts for abuse and postmaster etc, log into their mail accounts, and set up mail forwarding to whatever email account you want.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I didn't think the free version would let you add multiple domains on one account (50 accounts would be hell :-))?  One of the other problems is that info@domain1 and info@domain2 should go to different people, and my understanding of many systems is that you can't do that with their implementation of domain aliases?

Comment: The free version will let you add domain aliases, but you're right, it doesn't differentiate between domains.

Comment: I just checked my Google Apps account and it turns out they've changed things -- you can now manage completely separate domains from one master account. It says it's only available for the paid/edu versions but I didn't get any errors when I tried to add another domain.